# Do need to sanitize my output after sanitizing the input using Htmlspecialchars()

Tags: php

Please when a user inputs in a form, and on my validation page i validated the user input using      `htmlspecialchars($user_address);`     then save it into database.     now if i want to output the user address from the database lets say in profile page, do i need to sanitize what has already been sanitize before? I.e     `htmlspecialchars($row["user_addr"]);`     thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. What you would be doing there is called double encoding. For example, if you were to store the string:

```
"This & That"
```

Using `htmlspecialchars()` it would save in your database as:

```
&quot;This &amp; That&quot;
```

If you were to then use `htmlspecialchars()` on it before you displayed it you would get this in your source:

```
&amp;quot;This &amp;amp; That&amp;quot;
```

You would see this on the page:

```
&quot;This &amp; That&quot;
```

Comment: Thanks. So no need to sanitize twice if i already sanitized d input

Comment: If you sanitized it going in there shouldn't be a need to re-sanitize it when you are displaying it.